# kubectl exec into a container without using the random guid at the end of the pod name

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

To exec into a container in a pod, I use the following two commands (note the `template` flag in the first command trims the output to print just the name of the pods):

```
$ kubectl get pods --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
app-api-6421cdf4fd-x9tbk
app-worker-432f86f54-fknxw
app-frontend-87dd65d49c-6b4mn
app-rabbit-413632c874-s2ptw

$ kubectl exec -it app-api-6421cdf4fd-x9tbk -- bash
```

It would be nice to exec into the container without having to discover the random guid at the end of the pod name every single time. How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming a single pod?

Comment: No there are multiple pods

Comment: What pod do you want to exec to? The first one it finds? the last one? a random one?  Looks like you want an interactive session too.

Comment: I want to exec into the api pod. The other pods are the worker, frontend and rabbit queue. Just updated the question to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have a `Deployment` with the name `myadmin` and namespace `demo`. After deploy, you can exec into the deployment's pod by running the below command:

```sh
$ export id=( kubectl get pod -n demo | grep 'myadmin' | awk 'END {print $1}' | xargs echo) && kubectl -n demo exec -it $id -- bash
```

Comment: Even shorter: `kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod | grep api | awk '{print $1}') -- bash`

Comment: You could use the `-o name` option instead of using `awk` to reformat the output.

Answer (score 88):

You can exec into a pod using the deployment 
You can use the following command:

```
kubectl exec -it deploy/<deployment-name> -- bash
```

Comment: Note, if you have just deployed a new version you will almost certainly land in the terminating pod with this method instead of the new pod. [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1370)

Comment: What is the difference, if any, between this and the `--filename` option?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you expect this.

(`sed 's/pod\///'`  is used below because `kubectl get pod -o name` gives you names like `pod/rabbitmq-0` and you should cut first part)

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod -o name |  sed 's/pod\///' | grep api) -- bash
```

Similar to previous one you can use any known commands to find and sort needed objects. Providing version from your initial question

```
kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pod --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'| grep api) -- bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pods are probably related to a service (`kind: Service`), so you can use that to connect to an available pod:

```bash
kubectl exec -ti service/<your-service> -- bash
```